# Limit number of results in JPQL

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

How it is possible to limit the number of results retrieved from a database?

```
select e from Entity e /* I need only 10 results for instance */
```

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You can try like this giving 10 results to be fetched explicitly.

```
entityManager.createQuery(JPQL_QUERY)
             .setParameter(arg0, arg1)
             .setMaxResults(10)
             .getResultList();
```

It will automatically create native query in back-end to retrieve specific number of results, if the backend supports it, and otherwise do the limit in memory after getting all results.

Comment: "It will automatically create native query in back-end to retrieve specific number of results" - only if the database and the dialect supports it. If not, JPA will query all results and filter them in-memory. The developer must be aware of that, since it may affect the performance a lot. What's more, with some (more complicated) queries, JPA doesn't even try to use the LIMIT/TOP functionality, for instance when it would lead to wrong results.

Comment: @AdamDyga Yes, it's implementation specific, some provide them explicitly. Thanks for adding information.

Answer (score 21):

You can set an offset too using setFirstResult()

```
em.createNamedQuery("Entity.list")
  .setFirstResult(startPosition)
  .setMaxResults(length);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Spring data JPA, then you can use Pageable/PageRequest to limit the record to 1 or any number you want. The first argument, is the page no, and the second argument is the number of records.

```
Pageable page = PageRequest.of(0, 1);
Entity e = entityRepository.findAll(page);
```

Make sure the entityRepostitory interface extends JpaRepository (which supports sorting and pagination).