# Limit in subquery with JPQL

Tags: orm, jpa, jpa-2.0, jpql

I'd like to get the average price of my top 100 products via JPA2. The query should look something like this (my sql is a little rusty):

```
select avg(price) from (
      select p.price from Product p order by p.price desc limit 100)
```

but that is not working at all. I also tried this:

```
select avg(p.price) from Product p where p.id = 
       (select pj.id from Product pj order by pj.price desc limit 100)
```

this is working up until the limit keyword.

I read that limit is not available in JPQL.

Any idea on how to do this? Criteria would also be fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`LIMIT` is *not* supported by JPQL. Below is the sample-code using Criteria-API.

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Double> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(Double.class);
Root<Product> productRoot = criteriaQuery.from(Product.class);
criteriaQuery.select(builder.avg(productRoot.get("price")));
criteriaQuery.orderBy(builder.desc(productRoot.get("price"));
Double average = (Double)entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery).setMaxResults(100).getSingleResult();
```

or

```
Double average = (Double)entityManager.createQuery("select avg(p.price) from Product p order by p.price").setMaxResults(100).getSingleResult();
```

If this doesn't work, then you have to go for executing two queries – selecting definitely ordered records & then averaging them.

Else, go for a native query if portability is not an issue. You can accomplish same using a single query as many RDBMSes support restricting the number of results fetched from a database.

Comment: Ok i got it to work using 2 queries. Neither Hsql nor H2 seem to like the criteria and the hsql as it uses order by using avg() at the same time. Is it possible to do a subquery with the Criteria API?

Comment: yes, for subquery in Criteria API refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483576/jpa-2-0-criteria-api-subqueries-in-expressions/4668015#4668015. But the problem is in restricting the results to be fetched in JPA for subquery. In hibernate it can be done by query.setFetchSize(int fetchSize).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT AVG(SELECT PRICE FROM PRODUCT ORDER BY PRICE DESC LIMIT 100)
```

See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479128/jpql-limit-number-of-results) regarding the JPQL LIMIT work around.

Comment: That does not work. It just gives me an SQL exception saying it is an invalid order by expression. I am using hsql by the way.

Ok that work around would need 2 db queries right?

Comment: In your question you order one query by price and the other by purchases.  Is there a purchases column on your Product table?

Comment: sorry my mistake, it should always be ordered by price. I corrected it.

Comment: Change has been made, try it now.

Comment: I switched to H2 as there was some SQL grammar error with hsql. but also H2 has a problem with the order by:
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column "PRODUCT0_.PRICE" must be in the GROUP BY list; SQL statement:
select avg(cast(product0_.price as double)) as col_0_0_ from Product product0_ order by product0_.price desc limit ? [90016-154]

Comment: getting a hql syntax error. it seems that it cannot handle the sub query. The error occurs at the second select

Comment: JPQL does not allow subqueries within aggregates in the SELECT clause. Some implementations may allow it, but losing portability if doing that