# Is Select EXISTS() possible in JPQL?

Tags: jpa, jpql, jpa-2.0

I'm trying to run a query that checks if some conditions are true and returns a simple boolean result as output.  What makes it slightly tricky is that one of the conditions is to test for whether no results are returned for a set of criteria.

I'm currently using JPA-2.0 with hibernate as my provider, backed by MySQL.  I have gotten an example query working fine in MySQL, but when trying to get it running in JPQL it flops.  The MySQL query looks a bit like this:

```
Select exists(Select statement with criteria) 
  or not exists(Select statement with criteria);
```

I also got the same output using CASE, but as JPQL doesn't support that statement.

Anyways, when I try to use a similar query in JPQL I get the error:

> "unexpected end of subtree"

which from my understanding means that something is missing in the query. Does anyone have any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**This answer is obsolete. Yes, it is possible. Please refer to the correct answer from [Rene Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30841688/511736)**

---

No, it is not possible.

Refer to the [JPQL BNF](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11035_01/kodo41/full/html/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_bnf) documentation from oracle.

> **simple_cond_expression** ::= comparison_expression | between_expression | like_expression | in_expression | null_comparison_expression | empty_collection_comparison_expression | collection_member_expression | **exists_expression**
>
> **exists_expression** ::= [NOT] EXISTS(subquery)

Answer (score 30):

You can do a boolean query using a [case expression](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/2.3.0/apache-openjpa/docs/jpa_langref.html#jpa_langref_case_expressions).

As of JPA 2.0 (Java EE 6) you can [create a TypedQuery](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createQuery(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class)) .

```
String query = "select case when (count(*) > 0)  then true else false end from ......"
TypedQuery<Boolean> booleanQuery = entityManager.createQuery(query, Boolean.class);
boolean exists = booleanQuery.getSingleResult();
```

In JPA 1.0 (Java EE 5) you must use an untyped query.

```
Query booleanQuery = entityManager.createQuery(query);
boolean exists = (Boolean) booleanQuery.getSingleResult();
```

Comment: A more readable way is : "select (count(*) > 0) from ..."

Comment: @Reda This would still search the whole index/table although the DB could and should stop after it found the first result.

Comment: @T3rm1 yes you are right, but unfortunately I don't know if there is another solution to that problem

Answer (score 8):

In a project with Hibernate 5.2 (which supports JPA 2.1), and Spring Data Jpa 2.0.6, I successfully used this JPQL query:

```
@Query("SELECT COUNT(c) > 0 FROM Contract c WHERE c.person.id = :pid")
Boolean existContractForPerson(@Param("pid") Long personId);
```

In the logs, I read that the produced native query is the following:

```
select count(contract0_.contract_id)>0 as col_0_0_ from contracts contract0_ where contract0_.fk_person_id=?
```

Comment: But why bother computing a count that you're not going to use? Why not just try selecting one under a limit, that would be less work for your DB

Comment: @Amalgovinus JPQL does not support the LIMIT operation on its own. More information about JPA and JPQL is available here:
(https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence) 
(https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/JPQL)

Comment: Furthermore, the Entity Manager gives an API that can be used for limiting the results of any JPQL query. This is already answered here:

(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20679237/jpql-limit-query) 

(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479128/limit-number-of-results-in-jpql) 

In this case, and for the example I used earlier, I would use a different query:
`SELECT c FROM Contract c WHERE c.person.id = :pid`

and I would limit the results to 1, using:
`entityManager.setMaxResults(1) `

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively you could use a `select count(...)` and test whether it returns `0`. This should be almost as efficient without requiring to write much more code (in fact, the query itself will probably look simpler).

Comment: Not necessarily. `exists(...)` will probably exist after finding the first result. `count(...)` will have to scan many more index/table rows to determine the actual count.

Comment: @KonradGarus: It doesn't really matter though, when `count(..)` is the only solution that will work in JPQL anyway. So, when life gives you lemons...

Answer (score 2):

You have mismatched brackets. Try removing the one before the `not` (and the ones around the first exists):

```
select exists(Select statement with criteria) 
  or not exists(Select statement with criteria);
```

You don't need brackets around `exists()`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, but brackets or no the query still does not work in JPQL.

Comment: http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.2.0/apache-openjpa-1.2.0/docs/manual/jpa_langref.html#jpa_langref_exists So according to documentation at least exist part is correct from the question. "exists_expression ::= [NOT] EXISTS (subquery)"

Answer (score 2):

In a project that uses

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    ...
```

I successfully used an

```
exists(select s.primaryKey from Something s)
```

clause. So it might have changed. It could also be Hibernate-proprietary. Since a lot of people use Hibernate as a persistence provider, I thought I might add this here.

Answer (score 1):

It is more efficient for DB not counting all records. Create native query

Spring-Data-JPA

```
@Query(value = ".....", nativeQuery = true)
```

or JPA:

```
@NamedNativeQuery(name=.., query="..", resultClass=..)
```

Comment: You are trading theoretical efficiency for potential code breakage, since native query syntax is not verified until runtime.

Answer (score 0):

The solution with `count(*) > 0` triggered full table scan in Postgres for me:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYSE select count(*) > 0 from msg where type = 'ALERT';

Node Type   Entity  Cost            Rows    Time        Condition
Aggregate   [NULL]  462793 - 462793 1       24606.407   [NULL]
Gather      [NULL]  462793 - 462793 3       24606.397   [NULL]
Aggregate   [NULL]  461793 - 461793 1       24560.095   [NULL]
Seq Scan    msg     0.00 - 460781   335954  24489.559   ((type)::text = 'ALERT'::text)
```

The proper performant way is to **short-circuit** scan with `limit` or `top` keyword. As pagination is not portable you have to resort to `setMaxResults()`:

```
Query query = EntityManager.createQuery("select 1 from Book where ...", Integer.class);
List<Integer> tinyList = query.setFirstResult(0).setMaxResults(1).getResultList();
if (tinyList.isEmpty()) { ... }
```