# JPQL limit query

Tags: java, jpa-2.0, limit, jpql

How can I limit in a select query of JPQL named query? I need the limit to be done in the query level itself and not in the java layer!!!
I am trying to use

```
@NamedQueries(value = {
        @NamedQuery(name = UserNotification.QueryName.NOTIFICATION_DISPLAYED,
                    query = "SELECT un FROM UserNotification un " +
                            "WHERE un.orgId IN (:orgList) " +
                            "AND un.user.id = :userId LIMIT 5")
```

but in vain!!!

Please suggest

Answer (score 64, accepted):

`JPQL` does not provide a mechanism to limit queries.  This is most often achieved by using the `setMaxResults()` method on the `Query`.  If you must avoid specifying this in Java code, you could make a view in the database that contains your query and performs the limit.  Then map an entity to this view as you would a table.

Example:

```
List<String> resultList= query.setMaxResults(100).getResultList();
```

Answer (score 44):

In case you are working with [spring-data](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data/) you should use the [Pageable Interface](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Pageable.html). A sample code below,

My Service,

```
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest;

@Service
public class MyModelService {

    @Autowired
    private MyModelRepository myModelRepository;

    @Transactional
    public Page<MyModel> findMyModelTop5() {
        return myModelRepository.findMyModelTop5(new PageRequest(0, 5));
    }
}
```

My Repository,

```
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;

@Repository
public interface MyModelRepository extends JpaRepository<MyModel, Integer> {

    @Query("SELECT mm FROM MyModel mm")
    public Page<MyModel> findMyModelTop5(Pageable pageable);

}
```

You can find a more complete answer about the spring data available options [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48520827/use-queryhint-when-using-jpaspecificationexecutor#answer-48541323).

Comment: This is exactly what I've been looking for, and through all the searches, only you mention it this way... Thanks...

Comment: This was very useful. Much appreciated :)

Comment: Please note, this solution will start 2 SQL queries: One query for the SELECT with LIMIT and a second query with SELECT COUNT for the Page's metadata totalElements. This could be slow, when a query contains some additional WHERE clauses.

Comment: Works like a charm, but with one exception - I had to set my query as native, otherwise, it would not run my spring boot application.

`@Query(value = "SELECT mm FROM MyModel mm", nativeQuery = true)`

Comment: Very useful Thanks 

Comment: As of Spring Data 2.4.9 there is no `new PageRequest()`. You need to use the static method `PageRequest.of(page, size)`.

Answer (score 8):

For specific @NamedQueries where a limit is required, you can switch to @NamedNativeQuery

```
@NamedNativeQuery(
  name=UserNotification.QueryName.NOTIFICATION_DISPLAYED_LIMIT5,
  query="SELECT un.* FROM user_notification un " + 
        "WHERE un.user.id = ?1 LIMIT 5",
  resultClass=UserNotification.class
)
```

Not quite as smooth, but does the job.

Answer (score 0):

while executing the query with entity manager just write .setMaxResults(no of obj)

Comment: Same answer as: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20679415/1170330