# Use QueryHint when using JpaSpecificationExecutor

Tags: java, spring-data, eclipselink, specification-pattern

I use spring data and the `JpaSpecificationExecutor::findAll` method to fetch my models. How I could use query hints when calling this method?
The above source code works fine but I can't set QueryHint for my JPA provider (in my case EclipseLink).

```
@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Product> {
}

@Service
public class ProductService {

    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository productRepository;

    public List<Product> findByTitle(String locale, String titleToSearch) {
        return productRepository.findAll((Root<ProductCategory> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder builder) -> {
            return builder.equal(builder.function("jsonb_extract_path_text", String.class, root.<String>get("title"), builder.literal(locale)), titleToSearch);
        });
    }
}
```

The way I use the Query Hints using spring-data is the above,

```
@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Product> {

    @QueryHints(value = {
        @QueryHint(name = org.eclipse.persistence.config.QueryHints.BATCH_TYPE, value = "JOIN"),
        @QueryHint(name = org.eclipse.persistence.config.QueryHints.BATCH, value = "p.productCategory"),
        @QueryHint(name = org.eclipse.persistence.config.QueryHints.BATCH, value = "p.productFileList")
    }, forCounting = false)
    @Query("SELECT p FROM Product p")
    public List<Product> find();
}
```

I 've also found [this](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-144) which is unresolved yet.

Comment: have you tried to overwrite findAll in the ProductRepository interface and add the query hints?

Comment: The ProductRepository interface is been implemented by spring data at runtime (spring byte code instrumentation). Spring data supports custom implementation using a procedure that is described in the spring data docs. I will post an answer because this is my solution.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

When I want to create a query using spring-data I follow the above algorithm.

> **1) Is the query already provided** by the existing interfaces of spring-data like `CrudRepository`, `PagingAndSortingRepository`, `JpaRepository` etc?
>   Examples: `saveAndFlush` or `findAll` methods, more in [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.10.3.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories).

```
Product product = new Product();
// Setters..
productRepository.saveAndFlush();
```

> **2) Can I create a method using keywords inside method names?**
>   Examples: [count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10696490/does-spring-data-jpa-have-any-way-to-count-entites-using-method-name-resolving/27458590#27458590), more in [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.10.3.RELEASE/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation).

```
@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Integer> {

    Long countByTitle(String title);

    List<Product> findByTitleLikeAndVisible(String title, boolean visible);
}
```

> **3) Can I create a custom query method writing JPQL?**
>   Examples: [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.10.3.RELEASE/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query).
>   In this case spring data does not try to create the query using keywords inside method names, so the method names can be whatever you wish.

```
@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Integer> {

    @Query("SELECT COUNT(p) FROM Product p WHERE p.title=?1")
    Long countByTitle(String title);

    @Query("SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE p.title LIKE :title AND visible=true")
    List<Product> findByTitleLikeAndVisibleTrue(@Param("title") String title);
}
```

> **4) Do I want variable column names or variable where conditions? Then the solution is the Specification.**
>   Example: [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.10.3.RELEASE/reference/html/#specifications), [so answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47407043/spring-data-jpa-pass-column-name-and-value-as-parameters/48492077#48492077)

```
@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Product> {
}


@Service
public class ProductService {

    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository productRepository;

    public List<Product> findByColumn(String columnName, Object value) {
        return productRepository.find((Root<Product> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder builder) -> {
            return builder.and(builder.equal(root.<String>get(columnName), value));
        });
    }
}
```

> **5) Do I want more?** The solution is to get the EntityManager and use it like I used it without the spring data library. *(This is the answer to this so question)*
>   Example: [so answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30874214/how-to-access-entity-manager-with-spring-boot-and-spring-data/30886571#30886571), more in [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.10.3.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations)

```
// Create an interface and add the methods you wish to use with EntityManger.
public interface ProductRepositoryExt {
    public List<Product> findByTitle(String title);
}

// Implement the interface you created. Be careful the class name must be identical to the spring-data @Repository interface with the "Impl" appended.
public class ProductRepositoryImpl implements ProductRepositoryExt {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public List<Product> findByTitle(String title) {
//        em.getTransaction().begin();
        String sql = "SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE p.title=:title')";
        TypedQuery<ProductCategory> query = em.createQuery(sql, Product.class);
        query.setParameter("title", title);
        //  Add the query hints you wish..
        query.setHint(org.eclipse.persistence.config.QueryHints.BATCH_TYPE, "JOIN");
        query.setHint(org.eclipse.persistence.config.QueryHints.BATCH, "p.productCategory");

        return query.getResultList();
//        em.getTransaction().commit();
    }
}

// Extend this interface from your spring-data @Repository interface.
@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Integer>, ProductCategoryRepositoryExt {
}
```

Comment: Just a tip for nowadays in current Spring Data 2.2 about the **solution 4)**: the method **find** is now **findAll**.