# Why i'm getting 'QuerySyntaxException'?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

```
@Query("SELECT new com.ethihas.v1.blog.dto.PostDto(p.title, p.image, p.content, p.location,p.city, p.state, p.country) FROM Post p order by id desc limit 10")
List<PostDto> getAllPosts(@Param("from") Integer from, @Param("to") Integer to);
```

above is my query and below is constructor of PostDto

```
    public PostDto(String title, Integer image, String content, String location, String city, String state, String country) {
    this.title = title;
    this.image = image;
    this.content = content;
    this.location = location;
    this.city = city;
    this.state = state;
    this.country = country;
}
```

everything looks fine only for me but its causing below exception

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: limit near line 1, column 167 [SELECT new com.ethihas.v1.blog.dto.PostDto(p.title, p.image, p.content, p.location,p.city, p.state, p.country) FROM com.ethihas.v1.blog.model.Post p order by id desc limit 10]
```

Comment: [it looks like JPQL doesn't support `LIMIT`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20679237/jpql-limit-query). you can use `Pageable` as workaround.

Comment: tried with PageRequest
PageRequest(int,int,org.springframework.data.domain.Sort) has protected access in org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest

Comment: Not exact solution but can help , check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479128/limit-number-of-results-in-jpql

Comment: Also a solution with Pageable - https://stackoverflow.com/a/36790914/7505731

Answer (score 0):

Limit will not work JPQL, we can use Pageable to get records based on order

```
    Pageable firstPageWithTwoElements = PageRequest.of(0, 2, Sort.by("id").descending());
    Page<Post> pagedResult = postRepository.findAll(firstPageWithTwoElements);
    List<Post> postList = pagedResult.getContent();
```

above code will be give recent 2 entries sorted based on ID,