# Why does setFirstResult() in Query takes int parameter?

Tags: jpa, pagination, api-design

I'm implementing a custom pagination in Java and I'm wondering why does [Query](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Query.html)'s setFirstResult() method takes **int** as an argument? This means that I won't be able to paginate after the rows count in the DB exceeds 2.147.483.647?

Is there a way to use long instead?

Comment: serious? you are going to paginate through 2 billion records?

Comment: just in theory, e.g. I think FB has more than 2 billion posts

Comment: If you have such a huge result set, I think you need to paginate in the query conditions  (which you probably have to do for performance reasons anyway).

Comment: @Thilo my knowledge is limited but as far as I understand you can't use LIMIT(x,y) explicitly in JPQL (at least I could not) and Query solves this for you (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479128/limit-number-of-results-in-jpql), so basically this IS the query condition.

Comment: @Peter There's no real use case where you would be doing pagination with such a huge result set. If you think you need it, then you've made a serious design flaw somewhere.

Comment: a) You don't have to use JPQL b) this can be done with pagingTokens ("WHERE sortField1 >= ? AND sortField2>=? AND id > ?" )

Comment: @Kayaman You are quite right but there may be _very_ special cases when it's not caused by a design flaw I think.

Comment: @Thilo Thank you, I was just wondering why do I have to add unnecessary logic, and why doesn't Query support it by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `int` is large enough by quite a margin. Considering that when using `LIMIT/OFFSET` it's recommended to have an `ORDER BY` clause to get reliable results (otherwise you might get same rows on multiple pages), with a resultset of 2 billion rows you'll be sorting the results on the server, then skipping `OFFSET` rows to get your page, it'll be quite inefficient even way before you get to the limits of `int`.

Comment: ... meaning to paginate huge datasets, you have to put stuff like `WHERE sortField1 >= ? AND sortField2>=? AND id > ?` into your query anyway (i.e. page manually, removing the need for OFFSET)

Comment: @Thilo Exactomundo.

Comment: I guess your reasoning about ORDER BY is valid enough. Thank you both!

Comment: More like `WHERE sortField1 > ? OR (sortField1 = ? AND ( sortField2 > ? OR (sortField2 = ? AND id > ?)))` actually... Not pretty (unless you are sorting on a single and unique key). But necessary for performance.

Comment: @Peter That's based on the last line [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/queries-limit.html). Even though they say only that it *might* be inefficient, but it's wasted space and power in any case.

Comment: Also, if you are paging a billion records deep, chances are that there are concurrent updates, messing up the pagination as well.