# select the first record using @query in jpa

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have a jpa query that holds two records, from the two records I am unable to select the first record using @query in jpql

Here is my snippet

```
@Query("select h from History h where h.id =:id and h.status =:status " +
            "and h.type =:type and h.user =:user")
    History getAHistory(@Param("id") Long id, @Param("status") Status status,
                                         @Param("type") Type type, @Param("user") User user);
```

From findings I am trying to use the LIMIT 1 but no success

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Limit number of results in JPQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479128/limit-number-of-results-in-jpql)

Comment: no it does not.

Answer (score 0):

Your query returns a single `History` entity. If you plan to return more than one `History` entity you need to return a collection e.g. a list:

```
@Query("select h from History h where h.id = :id and h.status = :status " +
       "and h.type = :type and h.user = :user")
List<History> getAHistory(@Param("id") Long id, @Param("status") Status status,
                          @Param("type") Type type, @Param("user") User user);
```

Comment: so list is the only way to tackle this

Comment: It's one way to do it, or use a query and paramters that return just a single row. What is concerning that `id` parameter filtering returns more than one row. It's not a PK, so it's hard to tell what it is.